# How to create unique combinations out of provided keys-values?

Tags: algorithms

Let's say I have a struct Product **with an unknown and variable amount of attributes-values.** The attributes-values come from a user **at runtime.** One product with a unique combination of attributes and values form a *product_variant*.

For intance, user may create 4 attributes:

- size (5 values)
- material (3 values)
- design (2 values)
- colour (9 values)

and thus there'll be 5 * 3 * 2 * 9 = 270 unique product variants.

Example:

*product_variant* with:

```
%{ 
  size => m,
  material => paper,
  design => ds_abc,
  colour => red,
}
```

How do I traverse all the attributes with their respective values and thus create 270 unique product variants? What'll be an algorithm?

---

The number of attributes may be any and **isn't known at compile time.** There're 4 here, but there can be any number and they, amount and names, aren't known up front - they get resolved at runtime.

Not with a library one-line function.

Comment: Requests for code are off-topic here.

Comment: And your number of product variants is off if not all attributes need to be present.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't undestand your indian english